# how to update includePath. #include errors detected

Tags: c, compilation, include-path

I was trying to compile in vs code in my windows laptop And it said it couldn't open the source file "unistd.h" "#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. (and so on)"

I searched about the solutions for it for an hour, still can't fix it.

This is the code I tried to compile.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int     main()
{
    int i, j, rows;

    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);

    for(i = 1; i <= rows; ++i)
    {
            for(j = 1; j <= i; ++j)
            {
                printf("* ");
            }
            printf("\n");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

And
This is the c_cpp_properties.jason file

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.17763.0",
        "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

What should I add in this jason file to "upgrade includePath"?

Comment: It's possible that `unistd.h` is not included in VS code compiler, (UNIX Standard.) I suggest downloading DJGPP or Cygwin if you want to make UNIX programmes out-of-the box.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using `<angled> include` to include `unistd.h` (unless you have your own unistd.h in same directory)

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

> If a header file is included within <>, the preprocessor will search a predetermined directory path to locate the header file. If the header file is enclosed in "", the preprocessor will look for the header file in the same directory as the source file.

Comment: I did that of course! I'll add the code I wrote if that's better